# Refreshing radgrid automatically when grid datasource gets updated in the background telerik asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am have a radgrid to display the users from the table where it gets updated in the background. i want to refresh the grid whenever the record updated in the data source of the radgrid.

Comment: to be clear, you want the grid to automatically refresh, if for example a table in your database that you're using as a data source is updated via some other action (not on your page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Telerik RadAjaxManager, it will do the refresh automatically..

Edit:

Here's the code :

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"
        runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="controlID">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="GridId" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Comment: can you pls give me some samples for this?

Comment: I have edited my code, in controlID you can give the controlID which will effect the grid..

Comment: I searched around a lot for this and this fixed it for me.  The other answers pertain to binding the datagrid, which doesn't necessarily update the grid as it appears to the user.  Good answer

Comment: i'm looking to do the same thing but i'm rather new to asp i'm having trouble seeing how this works, how does this instruct the grid to update from a server side change?

Answer (score 2):

Just use following code for refresh RadGrid:

```
Radgrid1.Rebind();
```

Comment: i want to update the grid automatically when its data source get updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use need data source for binding the grid.

And after update the records you can user RadGrid.Rebind() method.